# Javascript How to remove Japanese/Chinese Yen symbol

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, str-replace

No idea why this doesn't work since I can obviously remove other symbols this way but this: `str = str.replace('¥', '');` fails to remove the symbol ¥ in question. Any ideas how to remove this thing?

I've also tried this `str = str.replace(/¥/g, '');` and this `str = str.replace(/\¥/g, '');` to no avail.

Obviously I can remove it by just knocking of the first character in the string but I thought there must be a way to actually detect this thing just in case it's not at the front and I need to remove it.

Comment: Can you please create a workable snippet

Comment: All three methods you tried are correct syntax and should work, the problem is something else.

Comment: @Yannick K It's definitely not anything else, I run several replace methods in the same function to replace other characters and text and they all work, it's only this symbol that doesn't.

Comment: Try  running `"¥".replace("¥","")` in your console. It worked for me.

Comment: Check if your str AND script file is encoded the same way the caracter you try to remove. i.e both in UTF8. If it can't be delete, it's because it's "bytes different"

Comment: Got a working answer below...somehow it must be a different ¥ to the one that is being displayed in the console log AFTER being replaced. Or after *failing* to replace it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple unicode code points for yen symbol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen_sign

try `str.replace(/[¥￥]/g, '')`

Comment: This works! Wow that was annoying since I was literally copying the symbol direct from the console log and it still wouldn't find it.

Comment: @Hasen If you were copying it from the console, you were probably copying a backslash. Some Japanese encodings render backslash as a yen sign.

Comment: @JLRishe I don't know because I copied it and pasted it into my code it still looked like the same yen symbol. But with text encodings and all, looks can be deceiving.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unicode value to replace the symbol.

Unicode value of `¥`: 00A5
Unicode value of `￥`: FFE5

```
const str = "¥Test String"
str.replace(/\u{00A5}|\u{FFE5}/gu, "Replace ")
```

Comment: Not sure why but it doesn't work. Only the other answer works.

Answer (score 1):

There are two "Yen" chars, [Unicode Character 'YEN SIGN' (U+00A5)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a5/index.htm) and [Unicode Character 'FULLWIDTH YEN SIGN' (U+FFE5)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffe5/index.htm).

To only match and replace those:

```
str = str.replace(/[\u00A5\uFFE5]+/g, "")
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/15VB0j/2).

To remove all 62 currency symbols that belong to `\p{Sc}`, [*Symbol, Currency*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm):

```
str = str.replace(/(?:[\$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u07FE\u07FF\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BF\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]|\uD807[\uDFDD-\uDFE0]|\uD838\uDEFF|\uD83B\uDCB0)+/g, "")
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/15VB0j/1).

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
str_rm_jap = function(str) {
  // we replace japanese blocks with nothing
  // reference at http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml
  
  // japanese style punctuation
  str = str.replace(/[\u3000-\u303F]+/g, "")
  // katakana
  str = str.replace(/[\u30A0-\u30FF]+/g, "")
  // hiragana
  str = str.replace(/[\u3040-\u309F]+/g, "")
  // kanji
  str = str.replace(/[\u4E00-\u9FAF]+/g, "")
  
  return str
}
```